# Permissions denied on files despite 777 mode

Tags: centos, permissions, chmod

I am getting a permission denied error on CentOS 6.10 64 bit

Kindly note that the "#" indicates a Root Level User prompt.

```
# cd /tmp
# chmod 777 file*
# /bin/ls -l file*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_00.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_01.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_02.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_03.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_04.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_05.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_06.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_07.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_08.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_09.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_10.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_11.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_12.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_13.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache   824 Sep 17 17:15 file_14.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache     1 Sep 17 17:15 file_15.dat
# cat file* > file.dat
cat: file_00.dat: Permission denied
cat: file_02.dat: Permission denied
# /bin/ls -l file.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root   10713 Sep 17 17:32 file.dat
```

The size of the full file is 10713, which is 824*13+1, meaning it was, successfully, copied every file except the files "00" and "02". A successful copy should be 12361 bytes, 824*15+1. However, there is nothing different about these two files, except that the machine refuses to let me read them.

The command "chmod 777" is redundant, just to emphasize the situation. Before running that command, permissions were all in the form "-rw-r--r--", which still means that I should not be getting a permission denied error.

There is no "." on the permissions, so theoretically, Selinux should not be involved, but even if it is involved, why is it only picking on just two files?

I can repeat the process that creates these files, and it will choose a different set of files to be unreadable. 
Does anybody have an explanation and fix for this?

**UPDATE:**

I have modified the process that creates the files. Previously it was receiving the data from a JavaScript client that broke an XLSX file into chunks to allow uploading spreadsheets of massive size. The server would receive the chunks as base64, decode each chunk to binary, then save it in a temporary file to be concatenated into a final XLSX file.

What it does now is save each temporary chunk as base64 (100% ASCII). Once all the chunks are uploaded, it reads each file, *then* decodes it to binary, and appends it to the final XLSX file.

Works fine. I think we'll leave it that way.

As a test, I wrote a quick 3 line program to read one of the base64 chunks, decode it to binary, then save it. Then I tried to read result. Guess what? **Permission denied on the binary file.**

So apparently, what makes the file unreadable is some pattern of data *inside* the file.

Using this method resolves the issue, but I still would like to know how a pattern of binary data *inside* a file creates a "Permission denied" error on the *outside*.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Goro. It's a headless server, no GUI, but I've tried "less", "more", and "vim" with the same Permission Denied error. The only thing I've been able to do is "mv" and "rm", but of course those affect the containing directory, not the file itself.

Comment: There are two pints here. Either the files were not copied correctly, or it is indeed a permission issue. for the later try `chmod 700 ` and see. You have to open the files to see if they were copied correctly!

Comment: what about `cat file_??.dat > file.dat` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Archemar -- Permission Denied on each file with a permission error, and each of the other files is copied successfully. Same result as cat file_* > file.dat

Comment: I remember if it has selinux context ls will show a Z flag at the end of output. So…check ls again? Is some other process running affecting these files?

Comment: @Goro, how would changing the mode from 777 to 700 make any difference? And how can I open the file to see if they're copied correctly if the system gives me a Permission Denied in the attempt? But what the hey, I'll try anything. EDIT -- tried it, no bueno.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @神秘德里克, sorry -- no, there is no "Z" and no other process can be affecting the files that I am aware of. And if there is a process affecting the files, it's latched on like a bulldog. The files are a day old, and I still can't open them.

Comment: only for these two particular files? That's weird, `getfacl`?

Comment: # getfacl file_00.dat

    # file: file_00.dat

    # owner: apache

    # group: apache

    user::rwx

    group::rwx

    other::rwx

Comment: And, btw, it's not exactly "only" these two files. If I run the process again (a javascript upload that divides the files into chunks), it will happen again with a different set of files. Then, it will "only" be whichever files it picks. About the only thing I can find commonality in is that, when it Works, it Works perfectly, but when it chooses to Deny, it always Denies the Zeroeth file. Then it will deny that one, and sometimes 1 or 2 others.

Comment: Worst case is Some thing wrong with  your harddisk. Thats Just a probably not true guess. Or even weirder guess, that something corrupted your filesystem when it's not mounted.

Comment: Is `/tmp` a separate filesystem? If so, what are its mount options?

Comment: Any errors  in /var/log/messages or /var/log/secure at the time of the `cat` failures?

Comment: Thanks for your response, @guzzijason -- no, /tmp is on root /, but even so, why would any mount options affect only SOME of the files? In this example, the process creates 16 files, and only 2 have Permission denied.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @MarkPlotnick -- no errors in /var/log/messages or /var/log/secure.

Comment: As a status update, I tried different chunk sizes for the javascript upload, and for THIS particular upload, only two worked. One was uploading all 12361 bytes in one single chunk, or a chunk size of 8192. Sizes that did not work included 1024, 2048 and 4096. They divided the file into fewer pieces, but always at least one experienced the Permission problem. So, it's "working" for THIS one example. I'm not feeling too confident that we won't find another example on a larger file that will Fail again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FINAL UPDATE**

Turns out our service provider had a Red-Hat Linux anti-virus program running. Which, obviously, I was unaware of.

Turn off the anti-virus, and all files magically become readable. Turn it back on, and a certain select few of the files happen to match some virus signature.

The anti-virus *should* be on the look-out for executable files. (the files were originally mode 644 when the problem surfaced)

There *should* be different error message.

Oh well. Henceforth we will encode the files in Base64, problem solved.

Thanks again to all who helped.

Comment: How does the antivirus hook into the system to not allow files to be erased?

Comment: @placidchat You will need to contact a Linux antivirus company with that question. All I know is, the antivirus thought the upload matched a virus signature, so therefore it locked it down.

Comment: I think they're using ebpf to insert pattern matching checks into open streams

Answer (score 1):

It might be a file attribute has been set. Try to list with `lsattr` command. Then you can unset with the activr attributes with `chattr -[acdeijstuADST] filename`.

You can find more info at [man chattr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr).

Comment: Thanks for your respons, @affan -- no bueno.

Comment: lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on /tmp/file_00.dat

Comment: @UncaAlby try run as root

Comment: @神秘德里克 -- I run using "sudo bash" which as close to root as I'm allowed, and until now, was all the root I ever needed. As far as I know, it's the same as logging in directly as root, except my access is logged somewhere for audit. More importantly, the process that creates the files and will ultimately need to read them is run by user "apache" and I don't think I want to change that.

Comment: Maybe it is locked by some process, can you try again with `lsof file_00.dat`. Or `lslk` or `lslocks`?

Comment: Thanks for your response, @affan, but I'm sure a file locked by some process would render a different error message.